# Find duplicates where another column have different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update records that will match a specific query, so I'm currently trying to figure out how to find a list of duplicate values where one column differs in value.

I have the following table definition

```
DocumentId (BIGINT)
NotePopupId (INT)
IsPopup (BIT)
Note (NVARCHAR(100))
```

My table might have data as follows:

```
1|1|False|Note1

1|2|False|Note2

2|1|False|Note1

2|2|True|Popup1

3|1|False|Note1

3|2|True|Popup1

4|1|False|Note1

4|2|False|Note2
```

I need to return a list of DocumentId that have more than one DocumentId defined but where The IsPopup field is True and False and ignore the ones where they are all false or all true.

I understand how to write a basic query that will return the total number of duplicates but I don't get how would I ensure that it will only returns the duplicates that have their IsPopup field set to true and false for 2 or more records with the same DocumentId.

So in this instance, based on the above, it would return DocumentId 2 and 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am inclined to handle a question like this using `group by` and aggregation:

```
select documentId
from table
group by documentId
having min(cast(isPopup as int)) = 0 and max(cast(isPopup as int)) = 1;
```

Comment: That's bang on and so simple!! Never thought that you could use the min & max aggregates to identify values this way. Learnt something new! Thanks :)

Comment: Quick question. I added 'and count(documentid) > 1' to the query  but I see that the results are the same. Is Using Min and/or Max somehow assumes that the count will be above one?

Comment: Those functions make no such assumption. But checking for two different values in a single column will require that you must have _at least_ two rows to work with. And so `count(documentid) > 1` is automatically true then.

Answer (score 2):

Find `Distinct Count` and filter the group's whose count is more than 1. Try this.

```
select DocumentId 
from yourtable 
group by DocumentId 
having count(Distinct IsPopup)>1
```

If you want to return documentId when there is only one IsPopup then use this

```
select DocumentId 
from yourtable 
group by DocumentId 
having count(Distinct IsPopup)>1 or count(IsPopup)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little more efficient

```
select distinct t1.documentId
  from table t1 
  join table t2
    on t1.documentId = t2.documentId 
   and t1.IsPopup = 'true'
   and t2.IsPopup = 'false'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  documentId
    from table
    group by documentId
     having min(convert(int,isPopup)) !=  max(convert(int,isPopup));
```